# How to pass **config file to SparkSubmitOperator from another operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I am trying to create a workfull dag. I have to use SparkSubmitOperator, but i don't know all config parameters before runtime. I get part of config from json, from hdfs, and some additional part from rest, from **kwargs['dag_run'].conf.

I tried to use different global variables and Xcom, but seems it doesn't work for SparkSubmitOperator.

```
import subprocess
from script import neoflex_config_handler
from config import config
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator

# context['dag_run'].conf['local_path']
# '{{dag_run.conf.hdfs_path}}'
# '{{dag_run.conf.java_class}}'

dag = DAG('ShapovalovTransformation1',
          description='Transformation-test',
          schedule_interval=None,
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20))

config_path = config.DevelopmentConfig.BASE_DATAGRAMM_DEPLOYMENTS_PATH + dag.dag_id
config_name = '{0}.json'.format(dag.dag_id)
_config = config_handler.get_config_hdfs(config_path, config_name)


# _config = config_handler.add_additional_application_args(_config, additional_args)
# _config = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=get_config) }}"

def push_config(**kwargs):
    additional_args = kwargs['dag_run'].conf
    print('Additional args: {0}'.format(additional_args))
    config_path_2 = config.DevelopmentConfig.BASE_DATAGRAMM_DEPLOYMENTS_PATH + dag.dag_id
    print('Config path 2: {0}'.format(config_path_2))
    config_name_2 = '{0}.json'.format(dag.dag_id)
    print('Config name 2: {0}'.format(config_name_2))
    _config_2 = config_handler.get_config_hdfs(config_path_2, config_name_2)
    print('Config from hdfs 2: {0}'.format(_config_2))
    _config_2 = config_handler.add_additional_application_args(_config_2, additional_args)
    print('Config full, hdfs+rest 2: {0}'.format(_config_2))
    return _config_2


def run_cmd_send_event(**kwargs):
    print('Running system command: {0}'.format('echo'))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'task completed'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
    s_return = proc.returncode
    return s_return, s_output, s_err


get_config = PythonOperator(task_id='get_config',
                            provide_context=True,
                            python_callable=push_config,
                            dag=dag)

run_etl = SparkSubmitOperator(task_id='run_etl',
                              dag=dag,
                              **_config)

send_event = PythonOperator(task_id='send_event',
                            dag=dag,
                            provide_context=True,
                            python_callable=run_cmd_send_event)

get_config >> run_etl >> send_event
```

FullConfig Example:

```
app_args = [
    'MASTER=yarn',
    'SLIDE_SIZE=400',
    'FETCH_SIZE=1000',
    'PARTITION_NUM=1',
    'FAIL_THRESHOLD=1000',
    'bootstrap=devhdp1:6667,devhdp2:6667,devhdp3:6667',
    'topics=load',
    'destination=/bdp/tmp/Channel1/version=version1',
    'startingOffsets={"load":{"0":1002}}',
    'endingOffsets={"load":{"0":1004}}',
    'USER=airflow',
    'HOME=\/user/airflow/',
    'ROOT_WORKFLOW_ID='+dag_name,
    'CURRENT_WORKFLOW_ID='+dag_name]

_config = {
    'java_class': '2StepsJob',
    'master': 'yarn',
    'deploy-mode': 'client',
    'driver-memory': '3G',
    'application': 'hdfs://devhdp-nn1.local-counter.tns:8020/bdp/etl-jars/hdfs/deployments/2Steps/1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar',
    'application_args': app_args
}
```

What i need:
After i get parameters from json and Rest(addittionaly i need get some parameters from zookeeper) i wanna construct a full version of **_config and pass it to SparkSubmitOperator.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solve it. Just wrote my own spark-submit-operator
Guys, where is my code solution, plz take your minuses back

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import 
SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.contrib.hooks.spark_submit_hook import SparkSubmitHook
from airflow.plugins_manager import *
import os
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.utils.operator_helpers import context_to_airflow_vars


class XcomSparkSubmitOperator(SparkSubmitOperator):

@apply_defaults
def __init__(self,
             op_args=None,
             op_kwargs=None,
             provide_context=True,
             templates_dict=None,
             xcom_task=None,
             application='',
             conf=None,
             conn_id='spark_default',
             files=None,
             py_files=None,
             driver_classpath=None,
             jars=None,
             java_class=None,
             packages=None,
             exclude_packages=None,
             repositories=None,
             total_executor_cores=None,
             executor_cores=None,
             executor_memory=None,
             driver_memory=None,
             keytab=None,
             principal=None,
             name='airflow-spark',
             num_executors=None,
             application_args=None,
             env_vars=None,
             verbose=False,
             *args, **kwargs):
    super(SparkSubmitOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.xcom_task = xcom_task
    self.op_args = op_args or []
    self.op_kwargs = op_kwargs or {}
    self.provide_context = provide_context
    self.templates_dict = templates_dict
    self._application = application
    self._conf = conf
    self._files = files
    self._py_files = py_files
    self._driver_classpath = driver_classpath
    self._jars = jars
    self._java_class = java_class
    self._packages = packages
    self._exclude_packages = exclude_packages
    self._repositories = repositories
    self._total_executor_cores = total_executor_cores
    self._executor_cores = executor_cores
    self._executor_memory = executor_memory
    self._driver_memory = driver_memory
    self._keytab = keytab
    self._principal = principal
    self._name = name
    self._num_executors = num_executors
    self._application_args = application_args
    self._env_vars = env_vars
    self._verbose = verbose
    self._hook = None
    self._conn_id = conn_id

def execute(self, context):
    airflow_context_vars = context_to_airflow_vars(context, in_env_var_format=True)
    self.log.info("Exporting the following env vars:\n" +
                  '\n'.join(["{}={}".format(k, v)
                             for k, v in airflow_context_vars.items()]))
    os.environ.update(airflow_context_vars)

    if self.provide_context:
        context.update(self.op_kwargs)
        context['templates_dict'] = self.templates_dict
        self.op_kwargs = context

    ti = context['ti']
    config = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=self.xcom_task)
    print("Config from XCOM: {0}".format(config))
    self._hook = SparkSubmitHook(
        conf=config.get('conf', self._conf),
        conn_id=config.get('conn_id', self._conn_id),
        files=config.get('files', self._files),
        py_files=config.get('py_files',  self._py_files),
        driver_classpath=config.get('driver_classpath',  self._driver_classpath),
        jars=config.get('jars',  self._jars),
        java_class=config.get('java_class',  self._java_class),
        packages=config.get('packages', self._packages),
        exclude_packages=config.get('exclude_packages',  self._exclude_packages),
        repositories=config.get('repositories', self._repositories),
        total_executor_cores=config.get('total_executor_cores', self._total_executor_cores),
        executor_cores=config.get('executor_cores',  self._executor_cores),
        executor_memory=config.get('executor_memory',  self._executor_memory),
        driver_memory=config.get('driver_memory',  self._driver_memory),
        keytab=config.get('keytab',  self._keytab),
        principal=config.get('principal',  self._principal),
        name=config.get('name',  self._name),
        num_executors=config.get('num_executors',  self._num_executors),
        application_args=config.get('application_args',  self._application_args),
        env_vars=config.get('env_vars',  self._env_vars),
        verbose=config.get('verbose',  self._verbose)
    )
    self._hook.submit(config.get('application', self._application))

def on_kill(self):
    super().on_kill()


class XcomSparkSubmitPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "XcomSparkSubmitModule"
    operators = [XcomSparkSubmitOperator]
```